# Sending/redirecting viewer to URL after receiving form info

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect

I am using a form tied to JS and PHP to capture form info and send it an email address...but I also want to send viewer upon clicking "submit" to be sent to a specific URL...
New to JS and PHP.
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: If you use jquery or angular, you can do a get request, in which success callback you can redirect.

Comment: $(function() {

 

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({

        preventSubmit: true,

        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {

            // additional error messages or events

        },

        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {

            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour

            // get values from FORM

            var name = $("input#name").val();

            var email = $("input#email").val();

            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message

            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Above is the JS script. What I'm getting is to use the 'header' function but where? This seems tricky as this function has to be used before content is sent. No?

Answer (score 1):

After sending the email in PHP:

```
header('location:http://example.com');
```

Comment: I think `Location` should be capitalized. I think most browsers will recognize the header regardless, but it's good practice to capitalize to follow standards.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that I want to use 'header' PHP...where do I put it? In the PHP file?

Comment: Yes, the last thing to do in the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use refresh meta tag after sending data:

```
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='www.example.com'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
window.location = '/some/page.php';
```

If you're submitting the form via Javascript. If you're letting the form's `action` run first, then use the PHP `header` function:

```
header('Location: /some/page.php');
```